# Moving raid array from USB to SATA

Tags: linux, software-raid, mdadm

I have a raid 1 array of two 2TB drives which I set up a while ago, both of them were connected through a sata->usb adapter (external HDD cases). Now I moved them into a proper PC but mdadm does not recognise the array or any of the drives as an array member. I can't mount the partitions.

How can I get the array working without any data loss?

Comment: One idea I have is to take one of the drives out, put it into the USB enclosure, create an array with the drive still in the pc, copy the files from the usb drive and then put it back. Would this work? If yes, how do I do it exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I'm not sure what caused the superblocks to be corrupted because even if I reassembled the external enclosure setup it did not work and I received the same errors regarding superblocks. After some reading I managed to solve the issue simply by creating an array:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --verbose --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
```

So basically I recreated the array with the same settings and now I can mount it and access all my files.

If you have a similar case I would try other things first because this seems sketchy at best and I'm pretty sure I was lucky but feel free to correct me.

**Edit:**

After rebooting the array did not assemble and raid information was lost. Solution was `sgdisk --zap /dev/sdx` for both disks, create array again with the command above, run `mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` (obviously deleting the old uuid) and `update-initramfs -u`. Now the array assembles after a reboot and everything works.